# Fetch zero if even there are no matching records

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have the data in table EMP_DETAILS

```
EMPLOYEE_NUMBER      ROLE
NSA5421              CONTRACTOR
NSA390               CONTRACTOR
E8923                EMPLOYEE
E2390                EMPLOYEE
```

I would like to have zero displayed even there are no records, I tried the following but it didn't get the desired result

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN cnt IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE cnt END cnt,
        CASE WHEN role IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE role END role
FROM
(SELECT   COUNT (*) cnt, role
     FROM   emp_details
    WHERE   employee_number = 'E3400'
GROUP BY   role)
```

Comment: based on ur data, with employee_number = 'E3400' ,there are no records is returned =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
select 
  NVL(y."ROLE", '0') "ROLE",  
  case when y."ROLE" is null then 0 else  COUNT(*) end cnt 
from(
      SELECT 'E3400' employee_number from dual
  )x left join emp_details y on x.employee_number=y.employee_number
group by "ROLE"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your inner query is returning nothing rather than null values.

```
SELECT   COUNT (*) cnt, role
     FROM   emp_details
    WHERE   employee_number = 'E3400'
GROUP BY   role
```

Use EXISTS clause

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN cnt IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE cnt END cnt,
        CASE WHEN role IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE role END role
FROM
(SELECT   COUNT (*) cnt, role
     FROM   emp_details
    WHERE   employee_number = 'E3400'
GROUP BY   ROLE
UNION
SELECT NULL, NULL  FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS
     ( SELECT   COUNT (*) cnt, role
     FROM   emp_details
    WHERE   employee_number = 'E3400'
GROUP BY   ROLE
     )
);
```

Comment: 2 records displayed for employee_number other than 'E3400'.

Comment: @techdo, UPDATED, please review.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way.

```
SELECT a.role,
       count(b.role)
  FROM emp_details a left outer join emp_details b
    on a.employee_number = b.employee_number
   and a.employee_number = 'E3400'
 group by a.role;
```

Output:

```
|      ROLE  | COUNT(B.ROLE)  |
-------------|---------- -----|
| CONTRACTOR |              0 |
|   EMPLOYEE |              0 |
```

[Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/106a8/1).